# Why the Limit of $\sqrt x$ is infinity?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, infinity

I'm a college student taking calculus for the first time. This past two weeks we were learning about limits and continuity. We are using Calculus Early Transcendentals book by Anton, Bivens, and Davis. Question 11 from exercise set 1.3 asks to find $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x}$. The book answer for $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x}$ is $+\infty$. Can anyone please explain me why the result is positive infinity. I do not know the procedure the book used to get the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For any $N$, take $M=N^2$.  Then for all $K>M$, $\sqrt K>N$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507386/prove-by-epsilon-delta-definition-lim-x-to-infty-sqrt-x-infty)

Comment: There are many ways you might supply context for such a terse problem statement.  It will not be clear to your Readers what specifically "having problems understanding" means without further explanation on your part.  Are there similar problems you saw worked in class or in your textbook, and you are motivated to apply those techniques to this problem?  I've voted to close for lack of context pending your edit to share why the problem is important to you or what you tried/researched before posting.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what else would it be if not $\infty$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$.

You can see clearly that as $x\to\infty \implies y\to \infty$ as well. [image]

Comment: This is not a rigorous mathematical proof

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If you want Epsilon Delta proof then it has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3507393/1145788)

Comment: it's not clear at all from the graph. arctan looks similar for example for a short while

Comment: @DavidP How does it look similar to arctan? This graph isn't defined for negative x which is clear from the graph, moreover it has already crossed beyond y=pi/2

Comment: how about comparing the graphs of the function 100arctan(x)+1 to sqrt(x), then reply. if you need it more specific, define the domain of the first to be [0, infinity)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The question says "explain me" , not "prove". This gives good intuition.

Comment: @DavidLui No it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the square root of numbers that grow without bound, the result grows without bound.

Answer (score 0):

| $N$ | $\sqrt{N}$ (approx.) |
| --- | --- |
| $5$ | $2.236$ |
| $50$ | $7.071$ |
| $2000$ | $44.72$ |
| $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ |

Keep taking larger and larger $N$, and you will see, while $N$ increases, $\sqrt{N}$
also increases. 
Further, this is an unbounded increase! That is, you can make $\sqrt{N}$ as large as possible by taking a large enough $N$. That is, $\sqrt{N}$ can be as large as it wants - there is no limit - that's why the limit is infinite!

Answer (score 0):

If you take the square of an arbitarily large number, the result is also large but always finite. Therefore, it's always possible to find a large enough $x$ where $\sqrt{x}$ is arbitrarily large, and so the limit is infinity. $$\sqrt{1}=1$$ $$\sqrt{100}=10$$ $$\sqrt{1000000}=1000$$ etc.